# Pokemon Call of Legends Starter Cards

Tags: deck-building, pokemon

My son got a bunch of Pokemon cards.  One set he bought used was the Call of Legends expansion.  The instructions say that there are two preset decks that you can use to start with to understand the game.  But all the cards are mixed together since its used.  Is there a specific icon on the card, to identify the starter decks of cards?  Or, is there any other designation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a set symbol for Call of Legends.    I can't link to it directly, but you can find the set symbol at the URLs below for the starter decks.

Call of Legends refers to a set of about 100 cards, some of which were used to assemble the starter decks.   The Set icon above would be used on all cards from Call of Legends, those that were included in one of the starter decks and also those cards that were included only in booster packs.   There isn't a symbol specific to the starter decks.

There were two starter decks for Call of Legends: Retort and Recon.   You can see the cards from each deck at the links below

http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Retort_(TCG)
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Recon_(TCG)